# AKS - combine addon HTTP application routing with nginx rewrite rule?

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm using the Azure AKS addon for HTTP application routing as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing). I deployed it using Terraform and it generally works:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = "nurse-ingress"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.nurse.metadata[0].name
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "addon-http-application-routing"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target" = "/$1"
    }
  }

  wait_for_load_balancer = true

  spec {
    backend {
      service_name = "nurse-service"
      service_port = 80
    }

    rule {
      host = "nurseapp.${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.addon_profile[0].http_application_routing[0].http_application_routing_zone_name}"
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = kubernetes_service.app.metadata[0].name
            service_port = 80
          }

          path = "/app/(.*)"
        }

        path {
          backend {
            service_name = kubernetes_service.nurse.metadata[0].name
            service_port = 80
          }

          path = "/nurse/(.*)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, it only works on the default backend (i.e. path=/). When I call the URL on /nurse or /app it does not work since the rewrite-target `/$1` does not seem to be taken into account. I will just get a 404 - since the nurse-service itself does expect calls on /foo and not on /nurse/foo

Should this be possible to configure to begin with and if so, any idea where my mistake is?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following will rewrite the path so that requests for `/sample/suffix` will be rewritten as `/suffix`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sample-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sample.YOUR-ID.westeurope.aksapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /sample/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sample
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure out. Btw, I'm on 1.19.6

Comment: i needed to put a leading slash in front of the rewrite-target: /$2 and remove the trailing slash in /sample to get this to work.